# Should I use inline formset or checkbox field for a bunch of OneToOne fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, inline-formset

I have three models in my Django app:

```
class Parent (models.Model):
     pass

class Sister(models.Model):
    pass

class Brother(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sibling = models.OneToOneField(to=Sister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to let users choose for which `Sister` instances they want to create a corresponding `Brother` **when** I create a new Parent (`Sisters` as you can see are not connected to a Parent).

The way I see it that when a user in a `ParentCreateView` I would also show them the list of all existing `Sisters` where they can put checkboxes in front of those for whom they would create a corresponding `Brother`. Then when they submit, a new Parent is created and corresponding number of Brothers attached to the sisters that have been chosen, and to a Parent that just has been created.

I can't figure out though the right design: should I use `inlineformsetfactory` for that? Should I pass there existing sisters? Or I can just pass a checkbox field with existing sisters to a form where new Parent is created, and then create corresponding brothers in a `post` method of `CreateView` class.